# Spring Boot Reading a Custom Environment specific file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following issue,
i want to read a environment specific custom file. So,something like
application-dev-kafka.properties,application-prod-kafka.properties  etc  and then bind properties.
I am aware of spring profiles.
I have thought about using @propertysource but again i am not sure what to specify in terms of the name of the file.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT-
profiles for me would be dev,prod etc. Not dev-kafka or prod-kafka.
for every profile and every component which requires configuration, I would like a profile specific file.

So application-dev-kafka,

application-dev-hazelcast,

application-dev-mysql.

application-prod-kafka,

application-prod-hazelcast,

application-prod-mysql,

application-int-kafka,

application-int-hazelcast,

application-int-mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, This is what I did.

I am using spring profiles and have added spring.profiles.active=dev in my application.properties file.

There are environment specific properties files also available. So, application-dev.properties,application-prod.properties etc which will be automatically detected by spring boot.

In my application,I have a component annotated with

```
      @PropertySource("classpath:${file-name}")
```

Here, the property-file-name is present in all environment specific properties files. So, depending upon which profile you run, 2 properties files will be automatically detected by spring boot. So for example-

If you run with profiles dev it will detect application.properties and application-dev.properties. Then depending upon the value of file-name in application-dev.properties, it will detect application-dev-kafka.properties.

Comment: Can you please explain this in details and with full code snippet?

Comment: What is exactly ur problem statement?

Answer (score 0):

Updated base on response.

Following the example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

have the following in your application.properties file.

```
list of your normal properties
---
spring.profiles: prod
spring.profiles.include:
  - prod-kafka
----
spring.profiles: dev
spring.profiles.include:
  - dev-kafka
```

Comment: For me profiles would be  dev and prod only. Not kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class for load your property files as you want.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("dev.properties")
    static class dev{}

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("prod.properties")
    static class prod{}
}
```

[image]

If you want to read a config file by different profiles (-Dspring.profiles.active)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Profile("dev")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("dev1.properties")
    static class dev1{}

    @Profile("dev")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("dev2.properties")
    static class dev2{}

    @Profile("prod")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("prod1.properties")
    static class prod1{}

    @Profile("prod")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("prod2.properties")
    static class prod2{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your configuration related environment specific kafka files in resources package,

[image]

You will get the value for spring active profiles by using below code,

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

String activeProfile = environment.getActiveProfiles()[0];
```

So you will get value of active profiles like dev, uat or prod in activeProfile variable, just create a environment specific file name using,

```
private String ACTIVE_PROFILES_KAFKA_FILE = activeProfile + "_kafka.yml";
```

So you will get the specific kafka file name like dev_kafka for dev, prod_kafka for prod and so on for respective environment and load the file in code as below.

```
MainClass.class.getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream(ACTIVE_PROFILES_KAFKA_FILE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `spring.profiles.active`  to specific the config file . For example use `spring.profiles.active=dev` to specific the application-dev.properties.
[image]

And you can also specific the config file when you run the application like :

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=prd
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply.
Check my question closely, I wanted application-<profile>-kafka.properties. and there can be multiple files like these.
application-<profile>-hazelcast.
application-<profile>-mysql

Answer (score -1):

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application-dev-kafka.properties")
class YourClassConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    //some method
    env.getProperty("your.property");
}
```

Comment: don't post code only answers, describe your answer.